# How to show pics from filcker profile in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a filcker profile page with the following url :

http://www.flickr.com/photos/...........

I need to create a template in django where pics from this page are displayed.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you serious? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858931/how-to-implement-a-yahoo-rss-news-feed-in-django-website, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879042/displaying-images-from-filcker-profile-in-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the Flickr API with one of the many Python modules or parse the feed on your Flickr profile page with Feedparser.

The former requires a Flickr API key, so for a quick go with the feed and use Feedparser to extract the URLs.

Extracting URLs:

```
import feedparser, re
d = feedparser.parse('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/'
    'photos_public.gne?id=62457326@N06&lang=en-us&format=rss_200')
url_list = []
for i in d['entries']:
    url_list.append(re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+\.jpg)",
        i['summary']).group('url'))
```

Rendering URLs in a Django template:

```
{% for url in url_list %}
    <img src="{{ url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

The limitation of the feed is the number of photos it contains.

- Flickr API ducumentation: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/
- Feedparser: http://www.feedparser.org/
- Your Flickr profile feed: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=62457326@N06&lang=en-us&format=rss_200

Comment: When i add or remove images from my photostream why is that not getting reflected in  the feed?

Comment: Because the data in the feed isn't live, generally feeds are generated every few minutes/hours to lighten the burden on the database. For live data you should use the API.